# Updating CentOS php version

Tags: centos, yum, php

I recently bought a VPS to host a Laravel website.
The problem I have is that the VPS has PHP version 5.3.3 and my Laravel project is created in PHP 7.3.
I tried yum update but it says that everything is up to date.
Also, it doesn't update my CentOS version, which is also outdated.
 Installing Epel installs an outdated version also.
How do I update everything properly?

Comment: Sounds like your version of CentOS is *brutally* out of date. You'll need to upgrade the entire system to a more recent version, beause PHP 5 is *way* past EOL.

Comment: How can I do that? yum update just doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'm sorry. Its just that every article uses yum update so. I'll look more into that

Comment: What are you paying for? If you are paying for a server and OS, then I would expect it to be up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 5.4 is the version packaged in the base repositories.  Don’t worry about it appearing so old, it gets security fixes from Redhat despite no longer supported by PHP. But if you want/need PHP 7.x, please [use the packages from SCL](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/php7).  Those are the most official means of using newer PHP on CentOS.

Another safe third party repository of PHP 7 packages is [IUS](https://ius.io/Usage/), which is maintained by Rackspace.

Edit: fixed version of PHP in base.